# how to debug html rendering issue on Apple mail client

Tags: iphone, html-email, email-client, apple-mail

We are facing few HTML/CSS issues on rendering our HTML email on Apple mail client on iPhones

Is there a way one can inspect and debug the issue?

Does Apple provide any emulator/tool to do the same?

Comment: Go with what Gwally is saying, you can use chrome dev tools to troubleshoot your emails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What worked for us is `Epiphany` browser. It mimicked the **restricted ability** of Apple mail client to render `HTML` far more closely than any of the solutions below -

- google `chrome`, `firefox`, `safari` in responsive design mode

Someone suggested to try emulator in XCode but I couldn't get hold of Apple mail in `Xcode -> Window -> Devices and Simulators`

Answer (score -1):

You can download an emulator in xcode and visually inspect most Apple devices in emulation.

A simple approach is to use Google Chrome. The engine powering Chrome is based on Webkit, which is the same html engine that powers Safari and IOS and iPadOS devices. The Inspector can allow you to inspect a variety of devices in emulation.

You can do much of this with Apple Safari as well.

A third approach is go post your code, define the problem and let people see if they can determine a fix.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks gwally. We tried google chrome but it didn't match the restricted ability of the Apple Mail client to render HTML. We also tried to use safari in Responsive design mode. yet to try emulator in Xcode. What worked for us is Epiphany browser. It mimicked the problems in Apple mail client more closely

Comment: @comiventor you can emulate Apple Mail on IOS devices with Simulator in Xcode. It’s my final check for emails.

Comment: I opened Xcode -> Window -> Devices and Simulators but didn't find any Apple mail? am i supposed to install it? will it also let me inspect it?

Comment: Chrome and Safari are not the same. Similar, yes. Both use Webkit, yes. They do not render the same. IMO the one browser I expect to render HTML/CSS differently is Safari.